# Drupal 7: Unable to find the wrapper "public"

Tags: php, drupal-7

Can anyone help me with this major issue I have. I have downloaded my Drupal 7 site running fine on current server, but I cant run it on localhost or on the new server where I am trying to move it...

It just gives me the "White Screen of Death"... and after commenting "set_error_handler" in boostrap.inc, I find out that the errors are all related to "public://" wrapper.

This is how all the errors look like:

> > Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: Unable to find the wrapper "public" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP

All these errors are coming from the following file:

> /includes/file.inc

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by just flushing all the caches. Used drush for that - `drush cc all`

Answer (score 1):

The wrappers are not loaded in the early stages of the drupal bootstrap, so you might want to double check if the wrappers are already instantiated at the time of calling them (which is not the case in hook_boot() or in the installation/update process).

The solution by Raheel Hasan (which he also posted on d.o) is realy bad, as it includes hacking core, removing core flexibility and adding a custom file to your root which makes your site suspectible to ddos attacks and of which the functionality is already found under the performance page on the admin panel.

At the moment I see no solution where you can use the stream wrappers before a full bootstrap is done.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error not like OP, but when I was trying to use Drush to do a node-export-export for a large amount of content so I can migrate from a D6 to D7 site.  In the D6 site, in the Site Configuration > Node Export settings page at the bottom it was trying to do a local file export to `public://`, so I set that to "Remote File Export, URL" and that error went away, because I have FTP access and can manually download the files.

Answer (score -2):

It took me many hours to find the solutions. I have posted it here:
[drupal.org/node/158043#comment-6490390](http://drupal.org/node/158043#comment-6490390)